# Keyboard Issues

Tags: cipher

```
d.nl mf t.fxrape ... g; ... oygjt cb kjg; ... ,dgoh mre. alh c ... hs  bry vls,
dr, yr ... udk cy
sfk or ln.ao. d.nl ... m. g er bry ... tbr, gy ... kjg; co kjd pcidy ... ;gkd yr rfk
ydco rb xgy c ... am hd;rdoakd ;s ... ln.ao. jdpr m. ydabt ... frg
```

---

**Hint 1**

> `q > ' : .` and `' > q : -`

**Hint 2** Locked until more incorrect or incomplete answers are submitted

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Stuck in black hole.

Explanation:

> Some words appear as if the user were trying to type in Dvorak with the keyboard set to QWERTY layout, while others appear the other way around.  Decoding:
>
> *help* *my* *keyboard* ... **is** ... *stuck* *in* **this** ... **weird** *mode* **and** *i* ... **do** *not* **know**
> *how* *to* ... **get** *it*
> **out** *so* *please* *help* ... *me* **i** *do* *not* ... *know* **if** ... **this** *is* **the** *right* ... **site** *to* **put**
> *this* *on* *but* *i* ... am **desperate** **so** ... *please* **help** *me* *thank* ... *you*
>
> (Here I have marked words typed in QWERTY on a Dvorak keyboard in **bold** and words typed in Dvorak on a QWERTY keyboard in *italics*.  Note that "am" is ambiguous since both "a" and "m" are in the same location in both layouts.)
>
> From here, if you group according to the "..." separators, this looks like it might be a Morse code encoding.  Now, if I interpreted the bold words as "." and the italic words as "-", then the resulting decoding made no sense to me -- not to mention that some of the letters, such as the fourth grouping on the third line, would decode to extended Latin letters.  On the other hand, suppose you interpret the bold words as "-" and the italic words as ".".  So, the Morse code version would read:
> ... - ..- -.-. -.- / .. -. / -... .-.. .- -.-. -.- / .... ?-- .-.. .
>
> Decoding the Morse code, this reads: stuck in black h(o|w)le.

Answer:

> I don't know what platform you're on.  But for the immediate problem you posted, I would presume you have some sort of mode switch key to switch between the two layouts.  Just pressing that once (without switching the layout you're trying to use) should hopefully bring you into sync with the intended layout.  Or, for the reverse, just switch the layout you're using to type without pressing the mode switch key.
>
> As for the hidden message, we unfortunately have no knowledge of physics that would solve that problem.  Given that you still managed to get a message to us somehow, you in fact know more than us on that point.  (Unless you meant it more figuratively, as in all your keyboard input is disappearing into a bit bucket?  If this is happening on Linux, for example, you might try pressing Ctrl-D to exit a `cat >/dev/null` command - or if you have not yet solved the keyboard layout issue, try either Ctrl-E or Ctrl-H.  Ctrl-C (or Ctrl-I / Ctrl-J) might also be worth trying to interrupt the current process.

Comment: Okay... The answer you provided is part of the puzzle, but not the final result I was looking for. It actually is a "cover" for another message... The only thing I can tell you is look into the "pattern to when it switches." Also, try to find out what Hint 1 means, I think it will be helpful to you at the step you're at.

Comment: Yep, you got it this time! I don't actually have a keyboard problem, I just needed help. It was the cause of a mission going wrong, and now the thing I got stuck in is causing me to spew random puzzles on the internet. :)

Comment: @yummypasta Right, I figured as much, I just had a bit of fun writing a mock serious reply...